# Inserting into a linkedList in order in C

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out inserting a node into my linkedList in order of the strings. I am having trouble with the pointers I believe, since I reach segmentation faults when I run the program. The node has two data fields an array of char for a string and a int representing a number. The list only needs to be sorted by names only.

```
 typedef struct node {
  char *name;
  int num;
  struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *head = NULL;

int insertInOrder(char *newName, int favNum) {
  Node *current = head;
  Node *newNode;
  Node *tempNode;
  int nodeIn = 0;

  if (head == NULL) {
    head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(head == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Out of memory\n");
      return 1;
    }
    head->name = newName;
    head->num = favNum;
    head->next = NULL;
  } else {
    while (current != NULL) {
      if (strcmp(newName, current->name) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Name already exists in the list\n");
        return 1;
      }
      if (strcmp(newName, current->name) < 0) {
        tempNode = current->next;
        newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if(newNode == NULL){
          fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Out of memory\n");
          return 1;
              }
        newNode->name = newName;
        newNode->num = favNum;
        newNode->next = tempNode;

        current->next = newNode;
        nodeIn = 1;
      }
      current = current->next;
    }
    if(nodeIn == 0){

      newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
      if(newNode == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Out of memory\n");
        return 1;
      }
      newNode->name = newName;
      newNode->num = favNum;
      current->next = newNode;
      newNode->next = NULL;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running `valgrind` and see at what line you get a segmentation fault?

Comment: Could You show call to `insertInOrder` ? I think the problem is there.

Comment: If the data string is less than current node's data string, you must insert before currentnode, not before nextnode, and the new node must be linked from the previous node.

Comment: ...and the logic is flawed also because after inserting a node, you continue to parse the list instead of quitting. So from that point on a new data node will be inserted at every node.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the flaws in your code which you need to look after --

**1**
`if(head!=NULL)` 
`{
write code for the case if (strcmp(newName, current->name) > 0) also.
}`

**2.**

If `strcmp(newName, current->name) < 0`  for the very first node,then you need to insert the node before the first node not after the first node which you have done.

**3.**

And after you have inserted the new node at any iteration of the `while loop` ,then you need to `break` out of the `while` loop.

I hope you may find these corrections useful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you test all these cases --

- Empty list
- First node in list.
- Last node in list with a list of more than 2
- Node between two items in list.
- 2nd node in list
- 2nd to last node in list.

By "test" all these cases I don't mean run the program and see it crash I mean look at the code and understand how that code would execute for each case.

I like to do little drawings of boxes and arrows when I'm seeing what it will do.  Don't be afraid to take it step by step.

Looking at the code above I can see many of the cases above you are not handling correctly so I'm not surprised you get seg faults.